# What is the drawback of storing latitude/longitude as integer in mysql?

Tags: mysql, optimization, coordinates

I have a large MySQL table containing +250.000.000 rows, where I store different kind of points and coordinates. The table has the following columns:

> NodeId      Lat      Lon

Till now, the Lat and Lon field were FLOAT(10,7) types, but I am experimenting in changing them to INT, because querying this table can be really slow, even though I've indexed both Lat/Lon columns together, and Lon column by itself.

If I am not mistaken, MySQL only uses a single index when searching.

The reason I want to change the two columns to Integer, is because I would partition the table by Lat for example, and index it by Lon, to make the searches faster.

Basically, I have two questions to which I am searching an answer for:

> 1. Would this kind of approach make my bounding box queries faster?
>
> 2. Are there any drawbacks of storing Latitude and Longitude coordinates as Integer values?

EDIT: What I failed to mention is that the original FLOAT values are multiplied by 10.000.000 before being stored as Integers.

Comment: Well, what about precision?

Comment: I am multiplying/dividing these floats/integers by 10.000.000, to maintain the original precision. As a signed INT can store from -2147483647 to 2147483647, that means the largest possible value is still managable by it. (180.0000000 would become 1800000000)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Are you aware that you can add an index with multiple columns?

Comment: Yes, and I just did that, but if I am not mistaken, even tough Lat/Lon are indexed together, MySQL can't cope with searching for both at the same time, and will only use one as an index.

Comment: If you have a compound index on both columns you can search on it. That's what it's for. It's the only thing it's for. Your question seems under-motivated. You should use the most natural datatype for the data concerned, and index according to your requirements.

Comment: These coordinates; are they points on Earth, or something more abstract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not likely to achieve a search performance improvement from either

1. partitioning the table or
2. changing the datatype of your lat/lon from FLOAT to INTEGER.

Why not?

- The amount of data stored is the same for FLOAT and INTEGER: 32 bits.
- FLOAT gives plenty of precision for GPS-resolution data. If you know and care about the differences between UTM and Lambert projections, use DOUBLE.
- Index range searches work properly for FLOAT, DOUBLE, and INTEGER.
- You'll need to do extra work to keep your index range searches from hitting a lot of partitions if you partition the table. Hitting lots of partitions makes searching slower.

If you're looking for points in a particular lat/lon bounding box, that will look something like this in MySQL:

```
SET @radius := 50;  /* 50km */
SET @units := 111.045l  /* kilometers per degree */
SET @lat := 40.7484;
SET @lon := ,-73.9857;

SELECT ...
 WHERE table.latitude 
  BETWEEN @lat  - (@radius / @units )
      AND @lat  + (@radius / @units )
  AND table.longitue
  BETWEEN @lon - (@radius / @units * COS(RADIANS(@lat))))
      AND @lon + (@radius / @units * COS(RADIANS(@lat))))
```

Notice that this takes the form

```
     table.latitude  BETWEEN constant AND constant
 AND table.longitude BETWEEN constant AND constant
```

The first of those two items is a straightforward range scan on the `latitude` column.  If it's indexed that is fast even if it's `FLOAT` data type.  A compound index on `(latitude, longitude)` should be pretty good, especially if you can keep your search radius fairly small.

Now, there's a complication.  With a quarter billion points it's possible your query is doing something like this.

```
     table.point_type = constant
 AND table.latitude  BETWEEN constant AND constant
 AND table.longitude BETWEEN constant AND constant
```

In that case, you need a compound index on `(point_type, latitude, longitude)`, so the query can do exactly the right thing.  With a table that size, you really need to understand your queries to get your indexes right.

Finally, with the number of points you have, you might consider using MySQL's geospatial extension for the location search. That is written up here. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/using-mysqls-geospatial-extension-location-finder/  But you can't create a compound index when one of its elements is geospatial.

Comment: The compound `INDEX(latitude, longitude)` will only use latitude -- because both factors are "ranges".  Similarly `(point_type, latitude, longitude)` won't make it to `longitude`.  That is, it will scan the wide stripe for that point_type and latitude range -- perhaps a million rows to test?  Granted, with ICP, the range scan will be just in the INDEX, but that is still costly, and has impact on the cache.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai You should really look into the answer Rick James gave. Running the naive solution given above on hundreds of millions of database entries will be considerably slower then a less naive approach. Worst case we are talking seconds of difference here for a single query.

Answer (score 1):

This will run circles around all other techniques.  However, it requires a bit of prep work:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

As that blog points out, multiplying by 10000 and storing in a MEDIUMINT would save 500MB in your case.  And the resolution is 16 meters / 52 feet.  If you need tighter resolution, then the INT solution (16mm / <1 inch) would be advised.  FLOAT, without the unnecessary (10,7) gives you 1.7m / 5.6ft.

Comment: If the author of the question really has 250 million data points, he should really consider reading the link. The accepted solution states that there would be no search performance improvement from partitioning. I don't think that this assumption holds for such amount of data.

Comment: @noamik Thanks for the comment.  In many situations, I state that partitioning does not help performance.  In _this_ case, I have carefully crafted the partitioning and the PRIMARY KEY to work together.  The result is code that runs in O(1).  Most indexes/algorithms don't do better than O(sqrt(N)).